# How to open encrypted by electronic signature pdf file using PdfSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, encryption, pdfsharp

Yo, Im trying to open pdf file that is encrypted with electronic signature. I using code like below. I get error : "The PDF document is protected with an encryption not supported by PDFsharp." I need to open this file to copy pages to new pdf ( need to merge encrypted pdf and other pdf). Can Anybody help me?

```
 public static void MergePdfs(List<string> allPdfFilesForInvoice)
    {
        string invoicePdfNameFull = allPdfFilesForInvoice.First();
        invoicePdfNameFull = invoicePdfNameFull.Replace(".pdf", "");
        invoicePdfNameFull = invoicePdfNameFull.Replace(".PDF", "");

        PdfDocument outDocument = new PdfDocument();

        for (int i = 0; i < allPdfFilesForInvoice.Count; i++)
        {
            string invoiceFilesPath = filePath + @"\" + allPdfFilesForInvoice[i];
            PdfDocument input = PdfReader.Open(invoiceFilesPath, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

            CopyPages(input, outDocument);
            outDocument.Save(savePdfsPath + @"\" + invoicePdfNameFull + "_kpl.pdf");

            input.Close();
            input.Dispose();

        }

        outDocument.Close();
        outDocument.Dispose();

        DirectoryOperations.DeleteMergedPdfFiles(allPdfFilesForInvoice);
    }
```

EDIT: there is no password - only encryption is signature

Comment: *"only encryption is signature"* - this is most likely incorrect: an interoperable digital PDF signature does not encrypt the document content. Just like @KJ I assume the PDF is encrypted using AES256 with the default password.

Comment: Which part of "The PDF document is protected with an encryption not supported by PDFsharp." don't you understand? "Not supported" means "not supported".

Answer (score 1):

Adding AES-128 encryption works fine. Also printing file by adobe that @KJ linked works
Thank you for respond guys.